# How does EF instantiate the DbContext property? Reflection?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

How does EF instantiate the DbContext property?

I mean, you have your context like

```
public class ProductContext : DbContext{ 
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; } 
}
```

Greate, than you use it like

```
using (var context = new ProductContext()) {     
    //context.Categories.XXXX
}
```

When you access the property **Categories** it is not NULL, it was already created by the **DbContext** some how.

So my question is, how does the DbContext instantiate those classes?

The only way that pop in my head is with **reflection**, at the DbContext constructor **new()**

```
//1º Get all properties that the type inherits from DbSet
//2º Instatiate with reflection/activator
```

Please, I do not want to know the code to instantiate the properties with **Reflection**, I know how to do it with **Reflection**, so why am I asking? Because it looks very slow by doing it with **Reflection**.

So maybe that is done in another faster *way* that I do not know. If it is, that *faster way* is what I am looking for.

Or it is actually create by reflection and that is one of the reasons for *"why you should not put 800+ tables in one DbContext"*.

Comment: Only once per context type, but reflection (what else it could be?)

Comment: The code is available [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/DbContext.cs).

Comment: Didn't know that the source was avaliable. Thanks I'll take a look at it.